# Masking zero inputs in LSTM in keras without using embedding

Tags: keras, lstm, embedding

I am training an LSTM in Keras:

```
iclf = Sequential()
iclf.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.3), input_shape=(None,2048)))
iclf.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
```

The input to each cell is a 2048 vector which is known and need not to be learned (if you will, they are the ELMo embeddings of the words in the input sentences). Therefore, here I have not the Embedding layer.

Since the input sequences have variable lengths, they are padded using `pad_sequences`:

```
X = pad_sequences(sequences=X, padding='post', truncating='post', value=0.0, dtype='float32')
```

Now, I want to tell the LSTM to ignore these padded elements. The official way is to use the Embedding layer with `mask_zero=True`. But, here there is no Embedding layer. How can I inform the LSTM to mask zero elements?

Comment: You can use `Masking` layer. You may find the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570297/2099607) useful in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

As @Today has suggested in the comment you can use the `Masking` layer. Here I added a toy problem.

```
# lstm autoencoder recreate sequence
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Masking
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


# define input sequence
sequence = array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], 
                  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8],
                  [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]])
# make sure to use dtype='float32' in padding otherwise with floating points
sequence = pad_sequences(sequence, padding='post', dtype='float32')


# reshape input into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_obs = len(sequence)
n_in = 9
sequence = sequence.reshape((n_obs, n_in, 1))

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(n_in, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_in,1) ))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_in))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(sequence, sequence, epochs=300, verbose=0)
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='reconstruct_lstm_autoencoder.png')
# demonstrate recreation
yhat = model.predict(sequence, verbose=0)
print(yhat[0,:,0])
```

Comment: Converting sequences of unequal lengths into a matrix produces an error. Pad your sequences before creating the matrix.