# Zero predictions despite masking support for zero-padded mini batch LSTM training in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, mini-batch

**Problem Statement**

I’m training a many-to-many LSTM in keras with tensorflow backend (tf version 1.13.1) on tagged text sequences to predict the tag of each element in the sequence using pretrained GloVe embeddings. My training regime involves mini batch stochastic gradient descent, with each mini batch matrix zero-padded column-wise to ensure equal length input to the network.

Crucially, because of custom constrains on my mini batches due to the nature of the task and the data, I am not using the keras embedding layer. My goal is to implement a masking mechanism for my zero-padded cells to ensure the loss computation does not spuriously treat these cells as genuine data points.

**Approach**

As explained in the keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding), keras has three ways in which a masking layer can be set up:

1. Configuring a `keras.layers.Embedding` layer with `mask_zero`
   set to `True`.
2. Adding a `keras.layers.Masking` layer;
3. Passing a mask argument manually when calling recurrent layers.

Because I am not using an embedding layer to encode my data for training, option (1) with a masked embedding layer is not available to me. So instead, I chose (2) and added a masking layer right after initializing my model. This change, however, does not seem to have had an effect. In fact, not only has the accuracy of my model not improved, at the prediction stage the model still generates zero predictions. Why does my masking layer not mask zero-padded cells? Could it have to do with the fact that in my dense layer I'm specifying 3 classes rather than 2 (thus including 0 as a separate class)?

**Limitations of Existing Resources**

Similar questions have been asked and answered, but I wasn't able to use them to resolve my issue. While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172852/masking-zero-inputs-in-lstm-in-keras-without-using-embedding) post received no direct response, a [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570199/multivariate-lstm-with-missing-values/52570297#52570297) post mentioned in a comment focuses on how to preprocess data to assign mask value, which is uncontroversial here. The masking layer initializtion, however, is identical to the one used here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670832/keras-lstm-with-masking-layer-for-variable-length-inputs) post mentions the same problem - a masking layer has no effect on performance - and the answer defines the masking layer in the same way as I do, but again focuses on converting specific values to mask values. Finally, the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353056/keras-masking-for-rnn-with-varying-time-steps) post provides the same layer initialization without elaborating further.

**Toy Data Generation**

To reproduce my problem, I have generated a toy 10-batch dataset with two classes (1,2). A batch is a variable-length sequence post-padded with zeros to a maximum length of 20 embeddings, with each embedding vector consisting of 5 cells, so `input_shape=(20,5)`. Embedding values for the two classes were generated from different but partially-overlapping truncated normal distributions to create a learnable but not trivial problem for the network. I've included the toy data below so you can reproduce the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional, Dropout, Masking
from keras import optimizers

# *** model initialization ***

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(20, 5))) # <- masking layer here
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(20, 5)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['mse'])

# *** model training ***

for epoch in range(10):

    for X,y in data_train:

        X = X.reshape(1, 20, 5)
        y = y.reshape(1, 20, 1)

        history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=20, verbose=0)

# *** model prediction ***

preds = pd.DataFrame(columns=['true', 'pred'])

for index, (X,y) in enumerate(data_test):
    X = X.reshape(1, 20, 5)
    y = y.reshape(1, 20, 1)

    y_pred = model.predict_classes(X, verbose=0)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['true', 'pred'])

    df['true'] = [y[0, i][0] for i in range(20)]
    df['pred'] = [y_pred[0, i] for i in range(20)]

    preds = preds.append(df, ignore_index=True)

# convert true labels to int & drop padded rows (where y_true=0)
preds['true'] = [int(label) for label in preds['true']]
preds = preds[preds['true']!=0]
```

This is the summary of the model with masking:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
masking_2 (Masking)          (None, 20, 5)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_4 (Bidirection (None, 20, 40)            4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 20, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, 20, 3)             123       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,283
Trainable params: 4,283
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I trained one model with and one without the masking layer and calculated accuracy using:

```
np.round(sum(preds['true']==preds['pred'])/len(preds)*100,1)
```

I got 53.3% accuracy for the model without masking and 33.3% for the model with masking. More surprisingly, I kept on getting zero as a predicted label in both models. Why does the masking layer fail to ignore zero-padded cells?

---

**Data for reproducing issue**:

```
data_train = list(zip(X_batches_train, y_batches_train))
data_test = list(zip(X_batches_test, y_batches_test))
```

X_batches_train

```
[array([[-1.00612917,  1.47313952,  2.68021318,  1.54875809,  0.98385996,
          1.49465265,  0.60429106,  1.12396908, -0.24041602,  1.77266187,
          0.1961381 ,  1.28019637,  1.78803092,  2.05151245,  0.93606708,
          0.51554755,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.97596563,  2.04536053,  0.88367922,  1.013342  , -0.16605355,
          3.02994344,  2.04080806, -0.25153046, -0.5964068 ,  2.9607247 ,
         -0.49722121,  0.02734492,  2.16949987,  2.77367066,  0.15628842,
          2.19823207,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.31546283,  3.27420503,  3.23550769, -0.63724013,  0.89150128,
          0.69774266,  2.76627308, -0.58408384, -0.45681779,  1.98843041,
         -0.31850477,  0.83729882,  0.45471165,  3.61974147, -1.45610756,
          1.35217453,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.03329532,  1.97471646,  1.33949611,  1.22857243, -1.46890642,
          1.74105506,  1.40969261,  0.52465603, -0.18895266,  2.81025597,
          2.64901037, -0.83415186,  0.76956826,  1.48730868, -0.16190164,
          2.24389007,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-1.0676654 ,  3.08429323,  1.7601179 ,  0.85448051,  1.15537064,
          2.82487842,  0.27891413,  0.57842569, -0.62392063,  1.00343057,
          1.15348843, -0.37650332,  3.37355345,  2.22285473,  0.43444434,
          0.15743873,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 1.05258873, -0.17897376, -0.99932932, -1.02854121,  0.85159208,
          2.32349131,  1.96526709, -0.08398597, -0.69474809,  1.32820222,
          1.19514151,  1.56814867,  0.86013263,  1.48342922,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.1920635 , -0.48702788,  1.24353985, -1.3864121 ,  0.16713229,
          3.10134683,  0.61658271, -0.63360643,  0.86000807,  2.74876157,
          2.87604877,  0.16339724,  2.87595396,  3.2846962 ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.1380241 , -0.76783029,  0.18814436, -1.18165209, -0.02981728,
          1.49908113,  0.61521007, -0.98191097,  0.31250199,  1.39015803,
          3.16213211, -0.70891214,  3.83881766,  1.92683533,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.39080778, -0.59179216,  0.80348201,  0.64638205, -1.40144268,
          1.49751413,  3.0092166 ,  1.33099666,  1.43714841,  2.90734268,
          3.09688943,  0.32934884,  1.14592787,  1.58152023,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.77164353,  0.50293096,  0.0717377 ,  0.14487556, -0.90246591,
          2.32612179,  1.98628857,  1.29683166, -0.12399569,  2.60184685,
          3.20136653,  0.44056647,  0.98283455,  1.79026663,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[-0.93359914,  2.31840281,  0.55691601,  1.90930758, -1.58260431,
         -1.05801881,  3.28012523,  3.84105406, -1.2127093 ,  0.00490079,
          1.28149304,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-1.03105486,  2.7703693 ,  0.16751813,  1.12127987, -0.44070271,
         -0.0789227 ,  2.79008301,  1.11456745,  1.13982551, -1.10128658,
          0.87430834,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.69710668,  1.72702833, -2.62599502,  2.34730002,  0.77756661,
          0.16415884,  3.30712178,  1.67331828, -0.44022431,  0.56837829,
          1.1566811 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.71845983,  1.79908544,  0.37385522,  1.3870915 , -1.48823234,
         -1.487419  ,  3.0879945 ,  1.74617784, -0.91538815, -0.24244522,
          0.81393954,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-1.38501563,  3.73330047, -0.52494265,  2.37133716, -0.24546709,
         -0.28360782,  2.89384717,  2.42891743,  0.40144022, -1.21850571,
          2.00370751,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 1.27989188,  1.16254538, -0.06889142,  1.84133355,  1.3234908 ,
          1.29611702,  2.0019294 , -0.03220116,  1.1085194 ,  1.96495985,
          1.68544302,  1.94503544,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.3004439 ,  2.48768923,  0.59809607,  2.38155155,  2.78705889,
          1.67018683,  0.21731778, -0.59277191,  2.87427207,  2.63950475,
          2.39211459,  0.93083423,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 2.39239371,  0.30900383, -0.97307155,  1.98100711,  0.30613735,
          1.12827171,  0.16987791,  0.31959096,  1.30366416,  1.45881023,
          2.45668401,  0.5218711 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.0826574 ,  2.05100254,  0.013161  ,  2.95120798,  1.15730011,
          0.75537024,  0.13708569, -0.44922143,  0.64834001,  2.50640862,
          2.00349347,  3.35573624,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.47135124,  2.10258532,  0.70212032,  2.56063126,  1.62466971,
          2.64026892,  0.21309489, -0.57752813,  2.21335957,  0.20453233,
          0.03106993,  3.01167822,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[-0.42125521,  0.54016939,  1.63016057,  2.01555253, -0.10961255,
         -0.42549555,  1.55793753, -0.0998756 ,  0.36417335,  3.37126414,
          1.62151191,  2.84084192,  0.10831384,  0.89293054, -0.08671363,
          0.49340353,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.37615411,  2.00581062,  2.30426605,  2.02205839,  0.65871664,
          1.34478836, -0.55379752, -1.42787727,  0.59732227,  0.84969282,
          0.54345723,  0.95849568, -0.17131602, -0.70425277, -0.5337757 ,
          1.78207229,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.13863276,  1.71490034,  2.02677925,  2.60608619,  0.26916522,
          0.35928298, -1.26521844, -0.59859219,  1.19162219,  1.64565259,
          1.16787165,  2.95245196,  0.48681084,  1.66621053,  0.918077  ,
         -1.10583747,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.87763797,  2.38740754,  2.9111822 ,  2.21184069,  0.78091173,
         -0.53270909,  0.40100338, -0.83375593,  0.9860009 ,  2.43898437,
         -0.64499989,  2.95092003, -1.52360727,  0.44640918,  0.78131922,
         -0.24401283,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.92615066,  3.45437746,  3.28808981,  2.87207404, -1.60027223,
         -1.14164941, -1.63807699,  0.33084805,  2.92963629,  3.51170824,
         -0.3286093 ,  2.19108385,  0.97812366, -1.82565766, -0.34034678,
         -2.0485913 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 1.96438618e+00,  1.88104784e-01,  1.61114494e+00,
          6.99567690e-04,  2.55271963e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 2.41578815e+00, -5.70625661e-01,  2.15545894e+00,
         -1.80948908e+00,  1.62049331e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.97017040e+00, -1.62556528e+00,  2.49469152e+00,
          4.18785985e-02,  2.61875866e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 3.14277819e+00,  3.01098398e-02,  7.40376369e-01,
          1.76517344e+00,  2.68922918e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 2.06250296e+00,  4.67605528e-01,  1.55927230e+00,
          1.85788889e-01,  1.30359922e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]]),
 array([[ 1.22152427,  3.74926839,  0.64415552,  2.35268329,  1.98754653,
          2.89384829,  0.44589817,  3.94228743,  2.72405657,  0.86222004,
          0.68681903,  3.89952458,  1.43454512,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.02203262,  0.95065123,  0.71669023,  0.02919391,  2.30714524,
          1.91843002,  0.73611294,  1.20560482,  0.85206836, -0.74221506,
         -0.72886308,  2.39872927, -0.95841402,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.55775319,  0.33773314,  0.79932151,  1.94966883,  3.2113281 ,
          2.70768249, -0.69745554,  1.23208345,  1.66199957,  1.69894081,
          0.13124461,  1.93256147, -0.17787952,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.45089205,  2.62430534, -1.9517961 ,  2.24040577,  1.75642049,
          1.94962325,  0.26796497,  2.28418304,  1.44944487,  0.28723885,
         -0.81081633,  1.54840214,  0.82652939,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.27678173,  1.17204606, -0.24738322,  1.02761617,  1.81060444,
          2.37830861,  0.55260134,  2.50046334,  1.04652821,  0.03467176,
         -2.07336654,  1.2628897 ,  0.61604732,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 3.86138405,  2.35068317, -1.90187438,  0.600788  ,  0.18011722,
          1.3469559 , -0.54708828,  1.83798823, -0.01957845,  2.88713217,
          3.1724991 ,  2.90802072,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.26785642,  0.51076756,  0.32070756,  2.33758816,  2.08146669,
         -0.60796736,  0.93777509,  2.70474711,  0.44785738,  1.61720609,
          1.52890594,  3.03072971,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 3.30219394,  3.1515445 ,  1.16550716,  2.07489374,  0.66441859,
          0.97529244,  0.35176367,  1.22593639, -1.80698271,  1.19936482,
          3.34017172,  2.15960657,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 2.34839018,  2.24827352, -1.61070856,  2.81044265, -1.21423372,
          0.24633846, -0.82196609,  2.28616568,  0.033922  ,  2.7557593 ,
          1.16178372,  3.66959512,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.32913219,  1.63231852,  0.58642744,  1.55873546,  0.86354741,
          2.06654246, -0.44036504,  3.22723595,  1.33279468,  0.05975892,
          2.48518999,  3.44690602,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.61424344, -1.03068819, -1.47929328,  2.91514641,  2.06867196,
          1.90384921, -0.45835234,  1.22054782,  0.67931536,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 2.76480464,  1.12442631, -2.36004758,  2.91912726,  1.67891181,
          3.76873596, -0.93874096, -0.32397781, -0.55732374,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.39953353, -1.26828104,  0.44482517,  2.85604975,  3.08891062,
          2.60268725, -0.15785176,  1.58549879, -0.32948578,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.65156484, -1.56545168, -1.42771206,  2.74216475,  1.8758154 ,
          3.51169147,  0.18353058, -0.14704149,  0.00442783,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.27736372,  0.37407608, -1.25713475,  0.53171176,  1.53714914,
          0.21015523, -1.06850669, -0.09755327, -0.92373834,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[-1.39160433,  0.21014669, -0.89792475,  2.6702794 ,  1.54610601,
          0.84699037,  2.96726482,  1.84236946,  0.02211578,  0.32842575,
          1.02718924,  1.78447936, -1.20056829,  2.26699318, -0.23156537,
          2.50124959,  1.93372501,  0.10264369, -1.70813962,  0.        ],
        [ 0.38823591, -1.30348049, -0.31599117,  2.60044143,  2.32929389,
          1.40348483,  3.25758736,  1.92210728, -0.34150988, -1.22336921,
          2.3567069 ,  1.75456835,  0.28295694,  0.68114898, -0.457843  ,
          1.83372069,  2.10177851, -0.26664178, -0.26549595,  0.        ],
        [ 0.08540346,  0.71507504,  1.78164285,  3.04418137,  1.52975256,
          3.55159169,  3.21396003,  3.22720346,  0.68147142,  0.12466013,
         -0.4122895 ,  1.97986653,  1.51671949,  2.06096825, -0.6765908 ,
          2.00145086,  1.73723014,  0.50186043, -2.27525744,  0.        ],
        [ 0.00632717,  0.3050794 , -0.33167875,  1.48109172,  0.19653696,
          1.97504239,  2.51595821,  1.74499313, -1.65198805, -1.04424953,
         -0.23786945,  1.18639347, -0.03568057,  3.82541131,  2.84039446,
          2.88325909,  1.79827675, -0.80230291,  0.08165052,  0.        ],
        [ 0.89980086,  0.34690991, -0.60806566,  1.69472308,  1.38043417,
          0.97139487,  0.21977176,  1.01340944, -1.69946943, -0.01775586,
         -0.35851919,  1.81115864,  1.15105661,  1.21410373,  1.50667558,
          1.70155313,  3.1410754 , -0.54806167, -0.51879299,  0.        ]])]
```

y_batches_train

```
[array([1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 2.,
        1., 1., 0.])]
```

X_batches_test

```
[array([[ 0.74119496,  1.97273418,  1.76675805,  0.51484268,  1.39422086,
          2.97184667, -1.35274514,  2.08825434, -1.2521965 ,  1.11556387,
          0.19776789,  2.38259223, -0.57140597, -0.79010112,  0.17038974,
          1.28075761,  0.696398  ,  3.0920007 , -0.41138503,  0.        ],
        [-1.39081797,  0.41079718,  3.03698894, -2.07333633,  2.05575621,
          2.73222939, -0.98182787,  1.06741172, -1.36310914,  0.20174856,
          0.35323654,  2.70305775,  0.52549713, -0.7786237 ,  1.80857093,
          0.96830907, -0.23610863,  1.28160768,  0.7026651 ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.16357113,  0.43907935,  3.40158623, -0.73923043,  1.484668  ,
          1.52809569, -0.02347205,  1.65349967,  1.79635118, -0.46647772,
         -0.78400883,  0.82695404, -1.34932627, -0.3200281 ,  2.84417045,
          0.01534261,  0.10047148,  2.70769609, -1.42669461,  0.        ],
        [-1.05475682,  3.45578027,  1.58589338, -0.55515227,  2.13477478,
          1.86777473,  0.61550335,  1.05781415, -0.45297406, -0.04317595,
         -0.15255388,  0.74669395, -1.43621979,  1.06229278,  0.99792794,
          1.24391783, -1.86484584,  1.92802343,  0.56148011,  0.        ],
        [-0.0835337 ,  1.89593955,  1.65769335, -0.93622246,  1.05002869,
          1.49675624, -0.00821712,  1.71541053,  2.02408452,  0.59011484,
          0.72719784,  3.44801858, -0.00957537,  0.37176007,  1.93481168,
          2.23125062,  1.67910471,  2.80923862,  0.34516993,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.40691415,  2.31873444, -0.83458005, -0.17018249, -0.39177831,
          1.90353251,  2.98241467,  0.32808584,  3.09429553,  2.27183083,
          3.09576659,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.6862473 ,  1.0690102 , -0.07415598, -0.09846767,  1.14562424,
          2.52211963,  1.71911351,  0.41879894,  1.62787544,  3.50533394,
          2.69963456,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 3.27824216,  2.25067953,  0.40017321, -1.36011162, -1.41010106,
          0.98956203,  2.30881584, -0.29496046,  2.29748247,  3.24940966,
          1.06431776,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 2.80167214,  3.88324559, -0.6984172 ,  0.81889567,  1.86945352,
          3.07554419,  3.10357189,  1.31426767,  0.28163147,  2.75559628,
          2.00866885,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.54574419,  1.00720596, -1.55418837,  0.70823839,  0.14715209,
          1.03747262,  0.82988672, -0.54006372,  1.4960777 ,  0.34578788,
          1.10558132,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])]
```

y_batches_test

```
[array([1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1.,
        2., 1., 0.]),
 array([2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0.])]
```

Comment: Which TF version are you using?

Comment: 1.13.1 - i've added the info to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First problem: your X data after reshaping is not what you expected. If you look at the first sample after reshaping, it is:

```
array([[[-1.00612917,  1.47313952,  2.68021318,  1.54875809,
          0.98385996],
        [ 1.49465265,  0.60429106,  1.12396908, -0.24041602,
          1.77266187],
        [ 0.1961381 ,  1.28019637,  1.78803092,  2.05151245,
          0.93606708],
        [ 0.51554755,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ],
        [-0.97596563,  2.04536053,  0.88367922,  1.013342  ,
         -0.16605355],
        [ 3.02994344,  2.04080806, -0.25153046, -0.5964068 ,
          2.9607247 ],
        [-0.49722121,  0.02734492,  2.16949987,  2.77367066,
          0.15628842],
        [ 2.19823207,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.31546283,  3.27420503,  3.23550769, -0.63724013,
          0.89150128],
        [ 0.69774266,  2.76627308, -0.58408384, -0.45681779,
          1.98843041],
        [-0.31850477,  0.83729882,  0.45471165,  3.61974147,
         -1.45610756],
        [ 1.35217453,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 1.03329532,  1.97471646,  1.33949611,  1.22857243,
         -1.46890642],
        [ 1.74105506,  1.40969261,  0.52465603, -0.18895266,
          2.81025597],
        [ 2.64901037, -0.83415186,  0.76956826,  1.48730868,
         -0.16190164],
        [ 2.24389007,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ],
        [-1.0676654 ,  3.08429323,  1.7601179 ,  0.85448051,
          1.15537064],
        [ 2.82487842,  0.27891413,  0.57842569, -0.62392063,
          1.00343057],
        [ 1.15348843, -0.37650332,  3.37355345,  2.22285473,
          0.43444434],
        [ 0.15743873,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ]]])
```

So actually no timestep is masked, because Masking layer only mask timesteps where all features are 0, so the above 20 timesteps are not masked because none of them are completely 0.

For the Masking layer, to ensure you have the mask propogated to the output layer successfully, you can do:

```
for i, l in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(f'layer {i}: {l}')
    print(f'has input mask: {l.input_mask}')
    print(f'has output mask: {l.output_mask}')

layer 0: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Masking object at 0x6417b7f60>
has input mask: None
has output mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
layer 1: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.wrappers.Bidirectional object at 0x641e25cf8>
has input mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
has output mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
layer 2: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x641814128>
has input mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
has output mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
layer 3: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed object at 0x6433b6ba8>
has input mask: Tensor("masking/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
has output mask: Tensor("time_distributed/Reshape_3:0", shape=(None, 20), dtype=bool)
```

So you can see that the final layer also has the output_mask, which means the masks are successfully propogated. You seem to have a misunderstanding of how Masking works in Keras, what it actually does is it will generate a mask, which is a boolean array, the shape of the mask is (None, Timesteps), since in your model definition, the Timestep dimension is always kept the same, so the mask will be propogated to the end without any changes. Then when Keras calculate loss (and of course when it calculate gradients), the timesteps which has a mask value False will be ignored. The Masking layer doesn't change the output value and of course your model will still predict class 0, what it only does is to produce a boolean array indicating which timestep should be skipped and pass it to the end (if all the layers accept the mask).

So what you can do is change one line of your model definition as follows and make your y_labels shifted by 1, which means your current classes:

0 -> 0 (since the loss of these timesteps will be ignored, not contributing to the training of the model, so whether it is 0 or 1 doesn't matter)

1 -> 0

2 -> 1

```
# I would prefer softmax if doing classification
# here we only need to specify 2 classes
# and actually TimeDistributed can be thrown away (at least in recent Keras versions)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='softmax')))
```

You can also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59313862/11819266 for understanding how the loss are calculated with / without masking.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer! For completeness, would you be able to at least post the edited model definition/initialization code with correctly implemented masking? From what I can understand, you have made three changes: (1) shift y-label encodings in data by -1, (2) modify masking layer input_shape argument from (20,5) to (None, 20); and (3) modify or eliminate final dense layer. Is this correct?

Comment: When I implemented the changes you mehtioned I got an error: "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected masking_2_input to have shape (None, 20) but got array with shape (20, 5)". This error arises regardless of whether I change my LSTM input layer to be (None,20).

Comment: The architecture is correct, the only thing you need to change is change the last layer to model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))) Then shift your label as mentioned

Comment: Also the data is incorrect, if you want to test the effectiveness of masking, you should make data like this:

a = np.random.randn(3, 20, 5)
a[0, -4:, :] = 0
a[1, -3:, :] = 0

This will make 3 samples, each has 20 timesteps, each timestep has 5 features. And the above makes the first sample padded with 4 timesteps, the second sample padded with 3 timesteps, the last sample is not padded.

Comment: I have a question. So if I managed to generate data like you suggest where all 0 padding is completely zero for that timesteps. I did that for both input and output. So I wonder if I put masking layers , the model will ignore of zero padding? Because in my case that is many to many problem so in output I have a zero padding too. I wonder if Masking layer can help me prevent calculate on zero padding both input and output?