# keras - embedding layer mask_zero causing exception at subsequent layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, word-embedding

I am working on a model based on [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04250) paper and I am getting an exception due to `GlobalMaxPooling1D` layer not supporting masking.

I have an `Embedding` layer with `mask_zero` argument set to `True`. However, since a subsequent `GlobalMaxPooling1D` layer does not support masking, I am getting an exception. The exception is expected, as it is actually stated in [the documentation of the Embedding layer](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) that *any subsequent layers after an `Embedding` layer with `mask_zero = True` should support masking*.

However, as I am processing sentences with variable number of words in them, I do need the masking in the `Embedding` layer. (i.e. due to the varying length of input) My question is, how should I alter my model that masking remains a part of the model, and does not cause a problem at `GlobalMaxPooling1D` layer?

Below is the code for the model.

```
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(dictionary_size, num_word_dimensions,
                            weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True,
                            embeddings_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
model.add(TimeDistributed(embedding_layer,
                          input_shape=(max_conversation_length, timesteps)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(m // 2, return_sequences=True,
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(h // 2, return_sequences = True,
                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
                        merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
crf = CRF(num_tags, sparse_target=False, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
model.add(crf)
model.compile(optimizer, loss = crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, as I am processing sentences with variable number of words in them, I do need the masking in the Embedding layer.

Are you padding the sentences to make them have equal lengths? If so, then instead of masking, you can let the model find out on its own that the 0 is padding and therefore should be ignored. Therefore, you would not need an explicit masking. This approach is also used for dealing with missing values in the data as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570297/2099607).