# Keras reports TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a beginner in Keras and just write a toy example. It reports a `TypeError`. The code and error are as follows:

**Code:**

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3, ))

cell = keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units=5, activation='softmax')
label = keras.layers.RNN(cell)(inputs)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=label)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mae',
              metrics=['acc'])

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
labels = np.array([1, 2])
model.fit(x=data, y=labels)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/david/Documents/code/python/Tensorflow/test.py", line 27, in <module>
        run()
    File "/Users/david/Documents/code/python/Tensorflow/test.py", line 21, in run
        label = keras.layers.RNN(cell)(inputs)
    File "/Users/david/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 619, in __call__
...
    File "/Users/david/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 473, in __call__
        scale /= max(1., (fan_in + fan_out) / 2.)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input to a RNN layer would have a shape of `(num_timesteps, num_features)`, i.e. each sample consists of `num_timesteps` timesteps where each timestep is a vector of length `num_features`. Further, the number of timesteps (i.e. `num_timesteps`) could be variable or unknown (i.e. `None`) but the number of features (i.e. `num_features`) should be fixed and specified from the beginning. Therefore, you need to change the shape of Input layer to be consistent with the RNN layer. For example:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, 3))  # variable number of timesteps each with length 3
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(4, 3))     # 4 timesteps each with length 3
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(4, None))  # this is WRONG! you can't do this. Number of features must be fixed
```

Then, you also need to change the shape of input data (i.e. `data`) as well to be consistent with the input shape you have specified (i.e. it must have a shape of `(num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features)`).

As a side note, you could define the RNN layer more simply by using the `SimpleRNN` layer directly:

```
label = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(units=5, activation='softmax')(inputs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer！

Answer (score 0):

I think @today's answer is very clear. However, not complete. The key thing here is that, if your input doesn't contain `num_features`, you have to make a `Embedding` layer next to the input.

So if you use:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3,))
embedding = Embedding(voc_size, embed_dim, ..)
X = embedding(inputs)
```

it also works.