# Keras fit_generator() - How does batch for time series work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, recurrent-neural-network

**Context:**

I am currently working on time series prediction using Keras with Tensorflow backend and, therefore, studied the tutorial provided [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/).

Following this tutorial, I came to the point where the generator for the `fit_generator()` method is described.
The output this generator generates is as follows (left sample, right target):

```
[[[10. 15.]
  [20. 25.]]] => [[30. 35.]]     -> Batch no. 1: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[20. 25.]
  [30. 35.]]] => [[40. 45.]]     -> Batch no. 2: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[30. 35.]
  [40. 45.]]] => [[50. 55.]]     -> Batch no. 3: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[40. 45.]
  [50. 55.]]] => [[60. 65.]]     -> Batch no. 4: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[50. 55.]
  [60. 65.]]] => [[70. 75.]]     -> Batch no. 5: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[60. 65.]
  [70. 75.]]] => [[80. 85.]]     -> Batch no. 6: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[70. 75.]
  [80. 85.]]] => [[90. 95.]]     -> Batch no. 7: 2 Samples | 1 Target
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[80. 85.]
  [90. 95.]]] => [[100. 105.]]   -> Batch no. 8: 2 Samples | 1 Target
```

In the tutorial the `TimeSeriesGenerator` was used, but for my question it is secondary if a custom generator or this class is used.
Regarding the data, we have 8 steps_per_epoch and a sample of shape (8, 1, 2, 2).
The generator is fed to a Recurrent Neural Network, implemented by an LSTM.

**My questions**

`fit_generator()` only allows a single target per batch, as outputted by the `TimeSeriesGenerator`.
When I first read about the option of batches for fit(), I thought that I could have multiple samples and a corresponding number of targets (which are processed batchwise, meaning row by row). But this is not allowed by `fit_generator()` and, therefore, obviously false.
This would look for example like:

```
[[[10. 15. 20. 25.]]] => [[30. 35.]]     
[[[20. 25. 30. 35.]]] => [[40. 45.]]    
    |-> Batch no. 1: 2 Samples | 2 Targets
  ---------------------------------------------
[[[30. 35. 40. 45.]]] => [[50. 55.]]    
[[[40. 45. 50. 55.]]] => [[60. 65.]]    
    |-> Batch no. 2: 2 Samples | 2 Targets
  ---------------------------------------------
...
```

Secondly, I thought that, for example, [10, 15] and [20, 25] were used as input for the RNN consecutively for the target [30, 35], meaning that this is analog to inputting [10, 15, 20, 25]. Since the output from the RNN differs using the second approach (I tested it), this also has to be a wrong conclusion.

Hence, my questions are:

1. Why is only one target per batch allowed (I know there are some
   workarounds, but there has to be a reason)?
2. How may I understand the
   calculation of one batch? Meaning, how is some input like `[[[40,
   45], [50, 55]]] => [[60, 65]]` processed and why is it not analog to
   `[[[40, 45, 50, 55]]] => [[60, 65]]`

***Edit according to todays answer***
Since there is some misunderstanding about my definition of samples and targets - I follow what I understand Keras is trying to tell me when saying:

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2 target samples.

This error occurs, when I create for example a batch which looks like:

```
#This is just a single batch - Multiple batches would be fed to fit_generator()
(array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]), 
                           array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]))
```

This is supposed to be a single batch containing two time-sequences of length 5 (5 consecutive data points / time-steps), whose targets are also two corresponding sequences. `[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]` is the target of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]` is the corresponding target of `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.
The sample-shape in this would be `shape(number_of_batches, number_of_elements_per_batch, sequence_size)` and the target-shape `shape(number_of_elements_per_batch, sequence_size)`.
Keras sees 2 target samples (in the ValueError), because I have two provide 3D-samples as input and 2D-targets as output (maybe I just don't get how to provide 3D-targets..).

Anyhow, according to @todays answer/comments, this is interpreted as two timesteps and five features by Keras. Regarding my first question (where I still see a sequence as target to my sequence, as in this edit-example), I seek information how/if I can achieve this and how such a batch would look like (like I tried to visualize in the question).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "single target per batch"? Your model could have one or mulitple output **layers**, and each of these layers could have a different output shape. So I don't understand what you mean by "single target" here. Please elaborate more.

Comment: I updated my question - Is it clearer now for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think you are mixing samples, timesteps, features and targets. Let me describe how I understand it: in the first example you provided, it seems that each input sample consists of 2 **timesteps**, e.g. `[10, 15]` and `[20, 25]`, where each timestep consists of two **features**, e.g. 10 and 15 or 20 and 25. Further, the corresponding target consists of one timestep, e.g. `[30, 35]`, which also has two features. In other words, **each** input sample in a batch **must** have a corresponding target. But the shape of each input sample and its target may not be the same.

Comment: In other words, in each training batch, we have as much targets as the input samples.

Comment: In the example taken from the linked tutorial I read this differently: The time-series (in this case just a `range(10, 110, 5)`) is split in sequences of length 2 (meaning two datapoints per sequence). In the first example one batch consists of two sequences which are used to predict a sequence of length two - not two features.

Comment: That's clearly a multi-variate timeseries: multiple (in this case two) features per each timestep. That's why the author has used `hstack` to construct that timeseries by stacking two uni-variate timeseries side-by-side. And it's just predicting the next timestep given the two previous timesteps.

Comment: Quoted from that tutorial: "Each sample will then be a three-dimensional array of [1, 2, 2] for the 1 sample, 2 time steps, and 2 features or parallel series. The output will be a two-dimensional series of [1, 2] for the 1 sample and 2 features." This confirms my assumptions and explanation.

Comment: Ah, concidering my mistake on this, my second question clarifies - thanks! Regarding my first question: Concidering my second example as a univariate time-series (meaning that `[10. 15. 20. 25.]` is a consecutive time-series of 4 time steps and I want to predict the next two steps `[[30. 35.]]`), how could I achieve what I intended in the example (meaning passing two samples / targets per batch)? Could I achieve this by reshaping it in the form the first example has?

Comment: If you would like to use RNN layers, then yes you need to reshape your arrays. For example, if you want the input of your model to have 4 timesteps where each timestep is only one feature, then the input training array must have a shape of `(num_samples, 4, 1)`. The same thing applies to target array: if you want to predict the next two timesteps, then it would have a shape of `(num_samples, 2, 1)` (though, this one is not a must, since it depends on the architecture of the model). E.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496805/2099607).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answers:**

> Why is only one target per batch allowed (I know there are some workarounds, but there has to be a reason)?

That's not the case at all. There is no restriction on the number of target samples in a batch. The only requirement is that you should have the same number of input and target samples in each batch. Read the long answer for further clarification.

> How may I understand the calculation of one batch? Meaning, how is some input like `[[[40,
>   45], [50, 55]]] => [[60, 65]]` processed and why is it not analog to `[[[40, 45, 50, 55]]] => [[60, 65]]`?

The first one is a multi-variate timeseries (i.e. each timestep has more than one features), and the second one is a uni-variate timeseris (i.e. each timestep has one feature). So they are not equivalent. Read the long answer for further clarification.

**Long answer:**

*I'll give the answer I mentioned in comments section and try to elaborate on it using examples:*

I think you are mixing samples, timesteps, features and targets. Let me describe how I understand it: in the first example you provided, it seems that each input sample consists of 2 timesteps, e.g. `[10, 15]` and `[20, 25]`, where each timestep consists of two features, e.g. 10 and 15 or 20 and 25. Further, the corresponding target consists of one timestep, e.g. `[30, 35]`, which also has two features. In other words, each input sample in a batch **must** have a corresponding target. However, the shape of each input sample and its corresponding target may not be necessarily the same.

For example, consider a model where both its input and output are timeseries. If we denote the shape of **each input sample** as `(input_num_timesteps, input_num_features)` and the shape of **each target (i.e. output) array** as `(output_num_timesteps, output_num_features)`, we would have the following cases:

1) The number of input and output timesteps are the same (i.e. `input_num_timesteps == output_num_timesteps`). Just as an example, the following model could achieve this:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

inp = layers.Input(shape=(input_num_timesteps, input_num_features))

# a stack of RNN layers on top of each other (this is optional)
x = layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(inp)
# ...
x = layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(x)

# a final RNN layer that has `output_num_features` unit
out = layers.LSTM(output_num_features, return_sequneces=True)(x)

model = models.Model(inp, out)
```

2) The number of input and output timesteps are different (i.e. `input_num_timesteps ~= output_num_timesteps`). This is usually achieved by first encoding the input timeseries into a vector using a stack of one or more LSTM layers, and then repeating that vector `output_num_timesteps` times to get a timeseries of desired length. For the repeat operation, we can easily use `RepeatVector` layer in Keras. Again, just as an example, the following model could achieve this:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

inp = layers.Input(shape=(input_num_timesteps, input_num_features))

# a stack of RNN layers on top of each other (this is optional)
x = layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(inp)
# ...
x = layers.LSTM(...)(x)  # The last layer ONLY returns the last output of RNN (i.e. return_sequences=False)

# repeat `x` as needed (i.e. as the number of timesteps in output timseries)
x = layers.RepeatVector(output_num_timesteps)(x)

# a stack of RNN layers on top of each other (this is optional)
x = layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(x)
# ...
out = layers.LSTM(output_num_features, return_sequneces=True)(x)

model = models.Model(inp, out)
```

As a special case, if the number of output timesteps is 1 (e.g. the network is trying to predict the next timestep given the last `t` timesteps), we may not need to use repeat and instead we can just use a `Dense` layer (in this case the output shape of the model would be `(None, output_num_features)`, and not `(None, 1, output_num_features)`):

```
inp = layers.Input(shape=(input_num_timesteps, input_num_features))

# a stack of RNN layers on top of each other (this is optional)
x = layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(inp)
# ...
x = layers.LSTM(...)(x)  # The last layer ONLY returns the last output of RNN (i.e. return_sequences=False)

out = layers.Dense(output_num_features, activation=...)(x)

model = models.Model(inp, out)
```

---

**Note that the architectures provided above are just for illustration, and you may need to tune or adapt them, e.g. by adding more layers such as `Dense` layer, based on your use case and the problem you are trying to solve.**

---

**Update:** The problem is that you don't pay enough attention when reading, both my comments and answer as well as the error raised by Keras. The error clearly states that:

> ... Found 1 input samples and 2 target samples.

So, after reading this carefully, if I were you I would say to myself: "OK, Keras thinks that the input batch has 1 input sample, but I think I am providing two samples!! Since I am a very good person(!), I think it's very likely that I would be wrong than Keras, so let's find out what I am doing wrong!". A simple and quick check would be to just examine the shape of input array:

```
>>> np.array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
               [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]).shape
(1,2,5)
```

"Oh, it says `(1,2,5)`! So that means **one** sample which has **two** timesteps and each timestep has five features!!! So I was wrong into thinking that this array consists of two samples of length 5 where each timestep is of length 1!! So what should I do now???" Well, you can fix it, step-by-step:

```
# step 1: I want a numpy array
s1 = np.array([])

# step 2: I want it to have two samples
s2 = np.array([
               [],
               []
              ])

# step 3: I want each sample to have 5 timesteps of length 1 in them
s3 = np.array([
               [
                [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
               ],
               [
                [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
               ]
              ])

>>> s3.shape
(2, 5, 1)
```

Voila! We did it! This was the input array; now check the target array, it must have two target samples of length 5 each with one feature, i.e. having a shape of `(2, 5, 1)`:

```
>>> np.array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]).shape
(2,5)
```

Almost! The last dimension (i.e. `1`) is missing (**NOTE:** depending on the architecture of your model you may or may not need that last axis). So we can use the step-by-step approach above to find our mistake, or alternatively we can be a bit clever and just add an axis to the end:

```
>>> t = np.array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> t = np.expand_dims(t, axis=-1)
>>> t.shape
(2, 5, 1)
```

Sorry, I can't explain it better than this! But in any case, when you see that something (i.e. shape of input/target arrays) is repeated over and over in my comments and my answer, assume that it must be something important and should be checked.