# LSTM 3D input 3D output dimension mismatch

Tags: keras

I have a simple LSTM network in Keras:

```
def create_model(x):
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=x.shape[2], input_length=x.shape[1]))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return lstm_model
```

and I am trying to train it on the data that has the following shapes:

> training data input: (100, 2784, 6), training data output: (100, 2784, 1) 
>   validation data input: (50, 27, 6), validation data output: (50, 27, 1) 
>   test data input: (50, 27, 6), test data output: (50, 27, 1)

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False, callbacks=[...])
```

I keep on failing on dimensions either because a) validation data is not the same shape as the training data or b) because the y shapes are not right

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Standalone code for convenience

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

x_train=np.arange(1670400)
x_train=x_train.reshape((100, 2784, 6))
y_train=np.arange(278400)
y_train=y_train.reshape((100, 2784, 1))

x_val=np.arange(8100)
x_val=x_val.reshape((50, 27, 6))
y_val=np.arange(1350)
y_val=y_val.reshape((50, 27, 1))

x_test=np.arange(8100)
x_test=x_test.reshape((50, 27, 6))
y_test=np.arange(1350)
y_test=y_test.reshape((50, 27, 1))


def create_model(x):
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=x.shape[2], input_length=x.shape[1]))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return lstm_model

model=create_model(x_train)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Since the number of timesteps is different in training and test phases, you need to set it to `None`, i.e. the `input_shape` would be `(None, 1)`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496805/2099607).

Answer (score 0):

This modification worked:
changing to **batch_input_shape** and adding **return_sequences=True** to the LSTM layer

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

x_train=np.arange(1670400)
x_train=x_train.reshape((100, 2784, 6))
y_train=np.arange(278400)
y_train=y_train.reshape((100, 2784, 1))

x_val=np.arange(8100)
x_val=x_val.reshape((50, 27, 6))
y_val=np.arange(1350)
y_val=y_val.reshape((50, 27, 1))

x_test=np.arange(8100)
x_test=x_test.reshape((50, 27, 6))
y_test=np.arange(1350)
y_test=y_test.reshape((50, 27, 1))

def create_model():
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(None,None,6), return_sequences=True))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return lstm_model

model=create_model()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
```